# Sort a Seq of case classes which contains another Seq of case classes

Tags: scala

I'm struggling in scala, because I want to sort a Seq of a simple case class which looks as follows:

```
case class A(seqOfB: Seq[B],
             order_index: Int)

case class B(name: String,
             order_index: Int)
```

As you can see, it contains another case class. What i want to do is to order a Seq which contains 2 Instances of A by the order_index of A. The first element in the Seq has the order_index 2 and has 1 B in its Seq. The second element in the Seq has the order_index 1 and has 2 B in its Seq:

```
val seqOfA = Seq(
        A(
           seqOfB = Seq(
            B(
              name ="cde",
              order_index = 21
            )
          ),
          order_index = 2
        ),
        A(
          seqOfB = Seq(
            B(
              name = "abc",
              order_index = 11
            ),
            B(
              name = "bcd",
              order_index = 12
            )
          ),
          order_index = 1
        )
      )
```

My code for sorting looks like this:

```
seqOfA.sortBy(_.order_index)
println(seqOfA)
```

Against my expectation, the sortBy() function does nothing and Seq isn't change in any way. Is it impossible in Scala to sort a construct like mine or is there an other way to achieve what I want?

I also tried sorting with the sortWith() function, but it also does nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are immutable data structures. You aren't sorting them in place - you are returning updated values from methods.

```
seqOfA.sortBy(_.order_index)
println(seqOfA)
```

Is the same as

```
val oldValue = seqOfA
val newValue = oldValue.sortBy(_.order_index)
println(oldValue)
```

If you want to see desirable results, just assign the result of sortBy to variable and print that variable.